# Swift Constraints in Subclass

Tags: swift, swift2, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

[image][image]I was wondering if there was a way to access constraints from a subclass. I have a custom view. I'm not sure if I can access the constraint I already have set in the UI, so I tried just creating the constraint from the subclass itself.

```
class PerformanceView: UIView {
    func initialize() {
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: superview, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.47, constant: 0);
        superview.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
}
```

The above code is not complete. Just showing what I was attempting to do. So two questions.

1) Can I access a constraint on the UI from the subclass.
2) If not, how can I create a height constraint in the subclass that is half of the superview height.

And I do have PerformanceView as the class for the View as you can see they all say Performance View in the left. 4 of them.

Comment: Just add an optional (implicitly unwrapped if you want) `NSLayoutConstraint` property and have this `initialize` method update it rather than making it a local variable. As an aside, I might choose a different name for this method, as this invites confusion with the `initialize` class method inherited from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is yes, there is a way. You can simply drag outlets to your constraints into your PerformanceView using the Assistant Editor.

[image]

As an adjunct - you can modify your constraints in code by using .constant. Modifying priorities is currently not supported though.

```
heightConstraint.constant = 230.0 //or any other value
```

In order for dragging outlets you have to make sure that you identified your PerformanceView properly in the storyboard editor. So select your PerformanceView in the left column. Then type "PerformanceView" into the highlighted field in the right column as shown below and hit return. Now you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: By Subclass. I meant to a UIView. Not a UIViewController.

Comment: Like Luke said :] - this works in either case.You are dealing with a regular outlet.

Comment: Take a look at my image I added.

Comment: I see it, but you haven't modified your question. Are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes I am. I do have PerformanceView as the class for the View. And still wont let me connect the constraint to the view..

Comment: Take a look at the new image in my answer. You have not properly subclassed your PerformanceView in the storyboard editor. That is the reason you're having problems.

Comment: Please see added Image. I do have this.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add your custom class to your UIView in your storyboard

[image]

under class type in your custom class - PerformanceView

create the connection variable to hold the constraint from your storyboard

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint?
```

then right click and drag the connection

[image]

Comment: By Subclass. I meant to a UIView. Not a UIViewController.

Comment: its the same process

Comment: Please look at image I added. It wont let me add the constraint to the UIView

Comment: see my edit. make sure you add your custom class to the uiview in the storyboard

Comment: I do have PerformanceView as the class for the View. And still wont let me connect the constraint to the view class file..

Comment: @KotaBear233 add your project as the module as well. its the section right under custom class

Comment: @KotaBear233 also type out the connection first. Then click and drag.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to add `@IBOutlet` from IB to `UIView` subview, it would appear that the standard trick of <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the control down to the source code in the assistance editor doesn't work.

Sometimes IB gets confused with outlets, but fortunately, there are other ways to add outlets and these other mechanisms seem to work fine. For example, you can manually add the `@IBOutlet` code to your `PerformanceView`:

```
class PerformanceView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

}
```

Now you can drag from the empty connector dot in the left margin next to the `@IBOutlet` up to the constraint:

[image]

Or, alternatively, <kbd>control</kbd>-click on the `PerformanceView` in the document outline, and then drag from the outlet listed in the popup to the constraint:

[image]