# Three UIImageViews stacked horizontally with scaling

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uistackview

I want to be able to have a bar at the top of my screen which holds three buttons, each one an image. Each image is exactly the same size and together, form one larger image (so the big image is split up into equals sized images - there can't be any space between each image, nor can there be any overlap.

I want to be able to detect the device size and adjust the image views accordingly so the images scale nicely.

Should I be using the a horizontal stack view for this?

As seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use stack view, but it is also simple enough to define constraints that define them to span the view and have equal widths (e.g. in VFL, `h:|[button1][button2(==button1)][button3(==button1)]|`. And then set height as appropriate. For the images, though, it might be easiest to make the buttons with no fill and just have a single image view behind them with the image.

For example:

```
var buttons: [UIButton]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttons = Array(0 ..< 3).map { _ -> UIButton in
        let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SomeViewController.didTapButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.topAnchor),
            button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.heightAnchor)
        ])
        return button
    }
    let views = ["button0" : buttons[0], "button1" : buttons[1], "button2" : buttons[2]]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[button0][button1(==button0)][button2(==button0)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
}
```

Yielding:

[image]

Or, as examined in view debugger:

[image]

---

If you want to do it with a stack view, it's very similar, the key issue is that you have to add constraints to define the buttons to have equal widths:

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(stackView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    stackView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.topAnchor),
    stackView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.heightAnchor),
    stackView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.leadingAnchor),
    stackView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.trailingAnchor)
])

buttons = Array(0 ..< 3).map { _ -> UIButton in
    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SomeViewController.didTapButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    return button
}

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    buttons[1].widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(buttons[0].widthAnchor),
    buttons[2].widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(buttons[0].widthAnchor)
])
```

Comment: That's great, thanks for the detailed answer. I may as well go with your first suggestion if there's no point in dealing with a StackView.

My idea is to use a different image based on the device being used, as I don't think the existing image will scale well as the device gets bigger/smaller. 

Would you suggest setting the size of the image view programmatically based on device size, then set the image of the view to fit inside that image view, and then place the transparent buttons on top? 

I'm unclear on the best way to handle images for different device sizes.

Comment: In my example, I just used a high resolution image and then set the ratio of the image view accordingly. But, yes, if you want pixel-perfect, you'll probably end up with different images for different device widths, and then you can add an `IBOutlet` for the height constraint of the image view. Then, look at the device width and set the image and the constraint's `constant` property accordingly.

Comment: I have an IBOutlet for the imageView, but when I try to resize the image view doing imageView.frame = CGRect, it has no effect. I'm guessing this is because the constraints I have applied on the storyboard are taking priority.

Is it something else I should be doing to programmatically set the height?

Comment: Yep, like I said, you have, presumably, a constraint for the height of the imageview. Add and `IBOutlet` for that constraint. Then you can adjust the `constant` of that constraint to be whatever height you want. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37737566/1271826

Comment: Correct, I have a constraint set in the storyboard. I had no idea you could add an outlet to a constraint - that makes much more sense now, thanks!

I'll give this a try now.